# Python Tkinter - Dictionary with Buttons - how do you disable them?

Tags: python, dictionary, button, random, tkinter

I created a 7x7 field of buttons with a dictionary.

**Problem 1:** I need to disable a User-Input amount of buttons randomly. 
The user writes a number x and x buttons will be blocked, but my               program has to choose them randomly...

**Problem 2:** The Rest of the buttons are usable. But if you click one, they will change the color and get `state = tk.DISABLED`.

How do I do all that with a dictionary full of buttons?

```
buttons = {}
for x in range(0, 7):
    for y in range(0, 7):
        buttons[tk.Button(frame_2, height=5, width=10, bg="yellow",command=self.claim_field)] = (x, y)
    for b in buttons:
        x, y = buttons[b]
        b.grid(row=x, column=y)
def claim_field():
    #changing Color of button and blocking the same button
```

Thank you for your answers, sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Please provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier to help. As a starting point: I would use a list instead of a dict, storing tuples of key, value and a reference to the button. Select some elements of the list randomly and use the reference to select the button and change its properties to disable the button or to activate color changing.

Comment: `command=lambda a=x, b=y:self.claim_field(a,b)` and `def claim_field(a, b):`

Comment: why do you use `for b in buttons:` ? can't you do directly when you create button ? `b = tk.Button() ; b.grid(x, y) ; button[b] = (x,y) ` ?

Comment: BTW: I would rather keep it as `buttons[(x,y)] = tk.Button()` and use `x,y` in `claim_field(x,y)` - this way `claim_field` will know `x,y` and it can  disable `button[(x,y)]`. And you can use `random.randint` to select random `x,y` to disable random button.

Answer (score 0):

I use `button[(x,y)] = tk.Button()` to keep buttons and now

- I use `random.randrange()` to generate random `x,y` and I can disable `buttons[(x,y)]`
- I use `lambda` to assing to button function with arguments `x,y` so function knows which button was clicked and it can disable it.

When you will disable random buttons then you have to check if it active. If it is already disabled then you will have to select another random button - so you will have to use `while` loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def claim_field(x, y):
    buttons[(x,y)]['state'] = 'disabled'
    buttons[(x,y)]['bg'] = 'red'

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

buttons = {}

for x in range(0, 7):
    for y in range(0, 7):
        btn = tk.Button(root, command=lambda a=x, b=y:claim_field(a,b))
        btn.grid(row=x, column=y)
        buttons[(x,y)] = btn

# disable random button        
x = random.randrange(0, 7)
y = random.randrange(0, 7)
claim_field(x, y)

root.mainloop()
```